# Stuck on mine dynamic form

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to make a extra field called "ages" on the same line or beside the child field.
So when I click the add/plus button it will give me a extra field with child and ages and not just one child field
Any one got time to help and show me how to do it correct because I can't make it to work.?

php

```
      <?php 
if(isset($_POST['name'])){
$name = $_POST['name'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$ageslist = "";
$childlist = "";
$more = TRUE;
$i = 1;
while ($more){
    if ((isset($_POST['child_'.$i])) && ($_POST['child_'.$i] != "") && ($_POST['ages_'.$i]) && ($_POST['ages_'.$i] != "")){
        $childlist .= $_POST['child_'.$i];
        $childlist .= "<br />";
        $ageslist .= $_POST['ages_'.$i];
        $ageslist .= "<br />";
        } else { $more = FALSE;
        } 
        $i++;
        }
        echo $name;
        echo "<br />";
        echo $phone; echo "<br />";
        echo "<br />";
        echo $ageslist;
        echo "<br />";
        echo $childlist; }
        ?>
```

javascript

```
            var i = 1;
            function addKid(){
                if (i <= 6){
                    i++;
                    var div = document.createElement('div');
                    div.style.width = "300px";
                    div.style.height = "50px";
                    div.style.color = "white";
                    div.setAttribute('class', 'myclass');
                    div.innerHTML = 'Child : <input type="text" name="child_'+i+'" ><input type="button" id="add_kid()" onclick="addKid()" value="+" /><input type="button" value="-" onclick="removeKid(this)">';
                    div.innerHTML = 'Ages : <input type="text" name="ages_'+i+'" ><input type="button" id="add_kid()" onclick="addKid()" value="+" /><input type="button" value="-" onclick="removeKid(this)">';
                    document.getElementById('kids').appendChild(div);
                    }
                    }
                    function removeKid(div) {
                        document.getElementById('kids').removeChild( div.parentNode );
                        i--; }
```

html

```
                    <form action="more_kids.php" method="post" >
                    Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br />
                    <div id="kids">
                        Child : <input type="text" name="child_1" >
                        Ages : <input type="text" name="ages_1" > <input type="button" id="add_kid()" onclick="addKid()" value="+" />
                    </div> Phone: <input type="text" name="phone"><br />
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
                </form>
```

Comment: in php `true` and `false` is lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

There is one mistake in javascript.

```
div.innerHTML = 'Child : <input type="text" name="child_'+i+'" ><input type="button" id="add_kid()" onclick="addKid()" value="+" /><input type="button" value="-" onclick="removeKid(this)">';
                div.innerHTML = 'Ages : <input type="text" name="ages_'+i+'" ><input type="button" id="add_kid()" onclick="addKid()" value="+" /><input type="button" value="-" onclick="removeKid(this)">';
```

You are overwriting div.innerHTML. The second one for ages should be div.innerHTML += '';

Also you have given div..style.color white. So labels are invisible.  Here is the script that works.

```
        <script>
    var i = 1;
        function addKid(){
            if (i <= 6){
                i++;
                var div = document.createElement('div');
                div.style.width = "500px";
                div.style.height = "30px";
                // div.style.color = "white";
                div.setAttribute('class', 'myclass');
                div.innerHTML = 'Child : <input type="text" name="child_'+i+'" >';
                div.innerHTML +=  ' Ages : <input type="text" name="ages_'+i+'" > <input type="button" onclick="addKid()" value="+" /> <input type="button" value="-" onclick="removeKid(this)"> \n';

                alert(div.innerHTML);
                document.getElementById('kids').appendChild(div);
                }
                }
                function removeKid(div) {
                    document.getElementById('kids').removeChild( div.parentNode );
                    i--; }    

    </script>
```